# Install Apache Cordova in windows phone SDK 8

Tags: apache, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I want to develop mobile applications for windows mobile Using Cordova. I downloaded Windows Phone SDK 8 and tried to integrate Cordova with it.

I tried copying "cordova-wp8.zip"  to

%My Documents%s\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates*

but it didn't work. I searched for internet for solution and couldn't find solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link might help you I use command lines to build cordova apps on different platforms check this link 
You first need to install node.js and configure your environment variables on your local machine then you will be able to use the command line to make mobile apps on wp8

If you follow the steps in this link you will manage to make it :)

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide

Hope this was helpful